# Reduce memory footprint while downloading a file with HTTPCLient

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, stream, dotnet-httpclient

I was wondering if there's a way I can avoid of getting all the buffer, then writing them to a file using HttpClient and File.WriteAllBytes.

Here's the code snippet I use

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadAsByteArray(string filename)
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Start downloading {filename} file at {DateTime.Now}");
    
    var result = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(filename);
    
    return result;
}
```

```
var bytes = await _downloadFileService.DownloadAsByteArray(fileDownload);

await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(fullFlePathName, bytes);
```

For quite huge file, the application memory grows really fast.

Comment: Use compression (GZIP).

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a74324dd-1508-495b-bcd4-0ae99a7ff16d/sending-compressed-content-with-httpclient?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `GetAsync` instead of `GetByteArrayAsync` and using `Content`'s `CopyTo`?

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
using var fs = new FileStream(...);
await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
```

---

Or using `GetStreamAsync`

```
using var responseStream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(uri);
using var fs = new FileStream(...);
await responseStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
```

Comment: are there are same efficient or GetStreamAsync more efficient?

Comment: @Emil This is a good question, quite frankly I don't think there is significant difference. It seems the [`GetStreamAsyncCore`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L332) adds a little overhead only.